# What is the difference between NOLOCK and TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, sql-server

What is the difference between:

```
sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Products WITH (NOLOCK)";
List<Product> products = thisDl.ExecuteQuery<Product>(sqlCmd).ToList();

sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM dbo.ProductItems WITH (NOLOCK)";
List<ProductItem> productItems = thisDl.ExecuteQuery<ProductItem>(sqlCmd).ToList();
```

And:

```
using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
    List<Product> products = (from p in dc.Products where select p).ToList();
    List<ProductItem> productItems = (from p in dc.ProductItems where select p).ToList();
}
```

Of the two, which is better to use?

Comment: Generally I wouldn't use either unless you're sure it's okay if your data isn't 100% accurate 100% of the time... which is fine for some applications but not for apps dealing with, for example, money.  Just be aware that when reading data this way it's possible to read duplicate records, or miss records entirely.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got d info want.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your statements they are the same. Now TransactionScope is the recommended one to use and NOLOCK is said to be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

**NOLOCK**
 table hint, also known as READUNCOMMITTED, is applicable to SELECT statements only. NOLOCK indicates that no shared locks are issued against the table that would prohibit other transactions from modifying the data in the table.

**The benefit** of the statement is that it allows you to keep the database engine from issuing locks against the tables in your queries; this increases concurrency and performance because the database engine does not have to maintain the shared locks involved. **The downside** is that, because the statement does not issue any locks against the tables being read, some "dirty," uncommitted data could potentially be read.

**TransactionScope** is a lighter, faster way to enlist modifications to data in a transaction. But the TransactionScope is more powerful and its grasp extends beyond databases. The TransactionScope can enlist other things like COM+ objects in a transaction, and you will shortly see the it appearing alongside LINQ for data queries and in ADO.NET for entities. TransactionScope: don't leave home without it. **TransactionScope** is an evolutionary step in supporting database transactions. Perhaps the idea was that an easier-to-use transaction model would be a model that will be used.

Comment: In addition to reading dirty data, it can also miss or read records twice if you happen to catch it when it's reorganizing data on the hard drive.